# Python: Reshaping array of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

is it possible to reshape an array of arrays like this:

```
np.array([[1,1,1,1,1,1],
          [1,0,0,0,0,1],
          [1,0,1,1,0,1]])
```

Into multiple 3x2 arrays, like this:

```
np.array([
    [[1,1],[1,0],[1,0]],
    [[1,1],[0,0],[1,1]],
    [[1,1],[0,1],[0,1]]])
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). "Implement this feature for me" is off-topic for this site. You have to make an honest attempt, and then ask a specific question about your algorithm or technique.

Comment: Assuming the top is `a`, you can do `a.reshape((3,3,2))` to get it into the bottom form.

Comment: I think it's not possible to reshape in a straight way because flatten forms of both shapes are different.

Comment: You'll need to do a `transpose` as well as `reshape`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the specific output you are looking for you need to reshape and transpose specific columns (by passing in the columns you want to transpose).

First you need to to reshape to get the groupings you want. Using `-1` acts like a wildcard and will make the middle value whatever it need to be to fill out the shape correctly.

Reshaping with `arr.reshape(3,-1, 2)` gives you:

```
array([[[1, 1],[1, 1],[1, 1]],
       [[1, 0],[0, 0],[0, 1]],
       [[1, 0],[1, 1],[0, 1]]])
```

The groups are correct, but want the columns grouped as rows. This is what [`transpose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) is used for. In this case you want to swap the first and second axes.

You can do that in one step like:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([
    [1,1,1,1,1,1],
    [1,0,0,0,0,1],
    [1,0,1,1,0,1]])

arr.reshape(3,-1, 2).transpose([1, 0, 2])
```

Outputing:

```
array([[[1, 1], [1, 0], [1, 0]],
       [[1, 1], [0, 0], [1, 1]],
       [[1, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]]])
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thank you so much! Could you briefly explain what's going on on the reshape?

Comment: @JúlioFortunato, see edit. Hopefully that will point you in the right direction.

Comment: what if the original list was a 30x30 one, would the `transpose` and `reshape` values be the same?

Answer (score 1):

`numpy` has the ability to `reshape()`.

```py
In [29]: a=np.array([[1,1,1,1,1,1],
    ...:           [1,0,0,0,0,1],
    ...:           [1,0,1,1,0,1]])

In [30]: a.reshape((3,3,2))
Out[30]:
array([[[1, 1],
        [1, 1],
        [1, 1]],

       [[1, 0],
        [0, 0],
        [0, 1]],

       [[1, 0],
        [1, 1],
        [0, 1]]])
```

This just changes the view, though. You can reassign if you want `a = a.reshape((3,3,2))`

Comment: Almost there! I kinda want the transposed array of this result, but if I use `a.reshape((3,3,2)).T` it turns an array of 3x3 arrays. How to make the transposed of this be three 3x2 arrays?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to answer if it's possible to reshape one array into another is to compare their flatten forms:

```
arr = np.array([[1,1,1,1,1,1], [1,0,0,0,0,1], [1,0,1,1,0,1]])
arr2 = np.array([[[1,1],[1,0],[1,0]], [[1,1],[0,0],[1,1]], [[1,1],[0,1],[0,1]]])
>>> print(arr.flatten())
[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1]
>>> print(arr2.flatten())
[1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1]
```

In this case it's not possible because results are different. You need to `swapaxes` additionaly:

```
arr.reshape(3,3,2).swapaxes(0,1)
```

[image]